# Setup for browser.js current its on watch all the time after call npm run test

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js

Setup for task in package.json

```
"test": "mocha -w test/helpers/browser.js src/**/spec.js",
```

Content of browser.js

```
require('babel-register')();

var jsdom = require('jsdom').jsdom;

var exposedProperties = ['window', 'navigator', 'document'];

global.document = jsdom('');
global.window = document.defaultView;
Object.keys(document.defaultView).forEach((property) => {
    if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
        exposedProperties.push(property);
        global[property] = document.defaultView[property];
    }
});

global.navigator = {
    userAgent: 'node.js'
};

documentRef = document;
```

After starting test all the time it's on watch and it won't end after test how to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `-w` flag.
From [Mocha's](https://mochajs.org/) docs:

```
-w, --watch                             watch files for changes
```

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem becaouse of use that browser.js on gitlab builder. Case with -w was the reason of not finished task.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this question is actually about how to exit the watch instead, you can do CTRL + C on the cmd to cancel the running process.

Comment: I know how to use cmd and ctrl+c but main element was specific setup for that task. Shorter way - i need close test task after tests.